# OrientDB 2.2.2 - Is there a way to suppress OAbstractProfiler$MemoryChecker Messages?

Tags: orientdb

We are running on 32bit windows and since upgrading from 1.4.1 to 2.2.2, we are seeing the following memory in stdout (numbers not exact):

```
INFO: Database 'BLAH' uses 770MB/912MB of DISKCACHE memory, while Heap is not completely used (usedHeap=123MB maxHeap=512MB). To improve performance set maxHeap to 124MB and DISKCACHE to 1296MB
```

With 32bit, we can only set a max of Xmx + storage.diskCache.bufferSize ~= 1.4gb without getting OOM or performance issues. Any combination of different sizes of either of these two configurable variables results in a variant of the above message.

**Is there a way to suppress the above profiler/memory checker messages?**

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the profiler with:

```
java ... -Dprofiler.enabled=false ...
```

Set that configuration in your `server.sh` or in the last section of `config/orientdb-server-config.xml` file.

Comment: Hello @Lvca, it looks like this option doesn't disable the OAbstractProfiler$MemoryCheckerMessages.